Footer on chatroom info pages isn't sticky to the bottom of the viewport
The footer element for the info tabs (and some other tabs) in chat rooms that don't have a lot of content height floats above the bottom of the viewport, creating a white rectangle at the bottom of the page.
Example 1 - Schedule Tab

Link to schedule tab
Example 2 - Access Tab

Link to access tab
This happens in Chrome 130.0.6723.117, with no plugins enabled, at 90% zoom; the problem also occurs at 100% zoom, although the white box is smaller.

What is the "access tab"?

@Joachim The tab for room access control settings; look at the top of the image.

I also can't reproduce it in Chrome.

I don't think that it's a bug, the footer in chat was never fixed the bottom of the viewport, as far as I can remember. E.g. you can see this here, list of active users in MSE chat domain. You can change that to a feature request asking to fix the footer to the bottom even when page contents aren't filling the screen,  but it's really really minor.

When we built those pages, we still supported IE7
